# How do I encrypt individual folders and files in an autonomous manner?

Tags: 14.04, encryption, dvd

I want to encrypt individual files and folders to backup them on DVD. So far, I only made password-protected .zip files, but I doubt that the security is very strong and I presume they are easy to crack, even with a long password.

Hence, I would like to know if there is a software that allows to put a password prompt when opening files/folders (instead of having to copy PGP keys, which themselves must be stored somewhere else...), even if I move the files outside of my computer (on DVD, USB, etc.).

So not just create an encrypted partition on folder inside my computer, but encrypt files and folders in an autonomous so that I can easily transfer them, just like making password-protected .zip files but with stronger security.

Thanks!

Comment: ZIP encryption is pretty strong actually. The weakness lies in the key derivation function (if you wait some years for computers to become more powerful), though RAR and 7z are a little better according to some researchers. The other portable and arguably cryptographically better options are a GnuPG (with a symmetric, pre-shared secret) and encrypted containers like TrueCrypt and its derivatives.